# Is there a (preferrably computer readable) Database of Ingress portals?

Tags: ingress

For a little project of mine I would need a database of Ingress portals (Name, Picture-URL and Location). 
I know i could extract it from the Intel map, but i assume someone else had made the effort before. It does not have to be "live" data, but a snapshot from the last month or so.

Do you know any such database? Or do you know a other way to gather global Ingress Portal information?

Answer (score 3):

There was an android application "[Portal Maps](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112903460388752504699/posts)" a few months ago, but Google/Niantic make them stop because of violations of the TOS of the game.

I'm not sure it is a good idea until Niantic release a real API to try to extract the data from their servers.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer it seems like some of the portals are imported from http://www.hmdb.org.  They have computer readable files.